# Is there a way to remove rows from dataframe in python having a certain word in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

[image]I have a dataframe with column names as "entity" and "definition". For example:
`df['entity']` and `df['definition']` where the 1st column has certain entity names and the second column has the definition. However for certain entities the definition has the word "None". I want to remove those rows which have the word "None" from the dataframe. I am attaching a screenshot of the same. Any lead on how to proceed?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: This image is of the output of my code

Answer (score 0):

If the "None" is a string:

```
df = df.loc[df["definition"] != "None"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"entity" : ["a", "b", "c"]})
df['Definition'] = ["None","b", "c"]
df.drop(df[df['Definition']=="None"].index, inplace = True) 
df.head()
```